# One To many How to merge 2 sets when the One is returning multiple records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 entities Users, Posts and Comments. I'm returning a list of comments given a Post ID through a stored procedure (currently it returns 2 sets - a list of comments and the list of users that made each specific comment). I want to combine each user into their specific comment.

This is the typical one (User) to many (comments) scenario, but the catch is that I'm not returning just one user and I'm trying to avoid adding an extra property for the IDs. In the end I want to be able to do the following [**comments[0].user.name**].

This is the code I currently have:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code I'm using to retrieve both sets:

```
public void GetCommentsByPostID(int ID)
{
        var cmd = Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetCommentsByPostID] @ID_Post";   
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID_Post", ID));

        try
        {
            Database.Connection.Open();

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            var comments = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
                .ObjectContext
                .Translate<Comment>(
                    reader,
                    "Comments",
                    MergeOption.AppendOnly);

            reader.NextResult();
            var users = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this)
                .ObjectContext
                .Translate<User>(
                    reader,
                    "Users",
                    MergeOption.AppendOnly);                
        }
        finally
        {
            Database.Connection.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just query the comments through a `DbSet` and a LINQ query?

Comment: Actually comments[0].User comes out as null when I do context.Comments.where(x => x.Post.ID == ID_Post). If I'm able to make this return the User as well foreach comment it'd be great.

Comment: Use the `Include` method.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this shortly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works as expected.